# Batch file for printing using shared printer in LAN

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a report and files that i have to print using the batch file. 
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\"  /t   it will print to the default printer. What i want is the file to be printed using shared printer.
how can i do this.? Any help.

Comment: Please include more information. I assume you're trying to print a pdf considering you're using Adobe Reader to print it. Add the relevant sections of code from your script.

Comment: im trying to print the pdf stored in specific location so that it ll print using the shared network printer..

Comment: Can you please let me know whether or not my answer has helped.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the help for the `print` command;

```
h:\>print /?
Prints a text file.

PRINT [/D:device] [[drive:][path]filename[...]]

   /D:device   Specifies a print device.
```

You simply need to do the following:

```
PRINT /D:\\shared\printer C:\path\to\file.pdf
```

Note that this may put the formatting a bit out of whack.

**Alternatively** you could just [change the default printer](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2564-how-to-set-the-default-printer-via-command-line-prompt) before running your original command.

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "\\Shared\Printer"
```

This may do a better job of preserving the correct formatting.

Comment: As an aside, this resolved my issue with printing from a Tomcat web application to a shared printer - I simply needed to provide the correct name for the printer: \\printersharehostname\printername.

Answer (score 2):

check [`printJS.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/printJS.bat)  - it emulates right click ->print and which uses default printer (`print` command uses `PRN` port which might be inactive).

usage is easy:

```
call printJS.bat someFile.txt
```